# Business Central - POST sales invoice line using REST API - setting multiple dimension values

Tags: dynamics-business-central, businesscentral

We use Business Central cloud API to POST sales invoices from other system

After creating the the sales invoice we create sales invoice lines to it
by using
{BC Endpoint}/SalesInvoiceLine API call
but we are able to enter only two shortcut dimensions
eg.

"Shortcut_Dimension_1_Code": "{value_fordim1}",
"Shortcut_Dimension_2_Code": "{value_fordim2}

HOWEVER **we need to set 4 dimensions for sales invoice line**

We have tried to search MS API documentation for this situation but no luck

So far we haven't found a way to set all 4 dimension values to sales invoice line directly.

Current assumption is that we should somehow add new dimension set entry to BC
(or search suitable combination from Dimension Set Entry table)
and then somehow tie the sales invoice line to that Dimension Set Entry ID. However we do not know what API calls we could use for this.

Any guidance or help appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to solve this by using:

POST {BC-endpoint}/SalesInvoiceLine  call

and just by entering the additional shortcut dimensions to the body

{

.......

```
"ShortcutDimCode4": "{value_for_dim4}",
"ShortcutDimCode5": "{value_for_dim5}"
```

}

Comment: I would guess that you are accessing some custom extension API, since standard BC API just doesn't have these properties. :-) Is your API endpoint one of those described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/api-reference/v2.0/endpoints-apis-for-dynamics

Answer (score 1):

In API v2.0 both entities salesInvoice and salesInvoiceLine contain a child object dimensionSetLines. If you run a request on the $metadata endpoint, you can find the definition in the API metadata.

```
<EntityType Name="dimensionSetLine">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="id"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="id" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="code" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="20"/>
<Property Name="parentId" Type="Edm.Guid"/>
<Property Name="parentType" Type="Microsoft.NAV.dimensionSetEntryBufferParentType"/>
<Property Name="displayName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="30"/>
<Property Name="valueId" Type="Edm.Guid"/>
<Property Name="valueCode" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="valueDisplayName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="50"/>
```

To view all dimensions on an invoice, send a GET request on

```
https://<Tenant URL>/api/v2.0/salesInvoices(<Invoice ID (GUID)>)?$expand=dimensionSetLines
```

To create an invoice with multiple dimension, include the dimensionSetLines object in the salesInvoice entity when sending the POST request.

```
{
    "invoiceDate": "2024-01-22",
    "postingDate": "2024-01-22",
    "customerNumber": "10000",
    "dimensionSetLines": [
        {
            "code": "SALESCAMPAIGN",
            "valueCode": "SUMMER"
        },
        {
            "code": "PROJECT",
            "valueCode": "VW"
        },
        {
            "code": "BUSINESSGROUP",
            "valueCode": "INTERCOMPANY"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, we were not able to actually use dimensionSetLines due some access issues.